# Convert JSON array to Java Class Object List

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSON string that comes from a WFC service. When I try to convert JSON array into List object, I've got the following error :

```
".JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: java.io.StringReader@41f27f18; line: 1, column: 1]"
```

The Java class (Card Class):

```
public class Card {
    public String ID;
    public String CompanyID;
    public String CompanyName;
    public String FiscalCode;
    public String Limit;
    public String StateID;
    public String CardState;
    public String Deleted;
    public String Sold;
    public String StartDate;
    public String InvoiceStartDate;
    public String Quantity;
    public String Value;
    public String CardTypeID;
    public String CardType;
    public String SoldChanged;
    public String DriverName;
    public String VehiclePlateNumber;
    public String VehicleID;
    public String Discount;
    public String ContractID;
    public String DiscountPerMonth;
    public String ProductID;
    public String ProductStateID;
    public String Mail;
    public String WithoutLimit;
    public String ContractSold;
    public String ContractLimit;
    public String NumberOfTransactions;
    public String DriverNameOnly;
    public String DriverSurnameOnly;
}
```

The Java code to deserialize :

```
strResponse = responseHandler.handleResponse(response);
if (strResponse.contains("Credit") || strResponse.contains("Debit")) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    strResponse= strResponse.replace("\"GetCardsResult\":", "");
    userCards = mapper.readValue(strResponse, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Card.class));
}
```

The JSON string:

```
{     "GetCardsResult":"[{\"ID\":3,\"CompanyID\":1155,\"CompanyName\":\"test\",\"FiscalCode\":null,\"Code\":\"1423127205\",\"Limit\":0.000,\"StateID\":1,\"CardState\":\"Activ\",\"Deleted\":false,\"Sold\":0.000,\"StartDate\":\"\/Date(1412974800000+0300)\/\",\"InvoiceStartDate\":\"\/Date(-62135596800000+0200)\/\",\"Quantity\":null,\"Value\":0.0,\"CardTypeID\":1,\"CardType\":\"Credit\",\"SoldChanged\":false,\"DriverName\":\"\",\"VehiclePlateNumber\":\"B 222 ART\",\"VehicleID\":null,\"Discount\":null,\"ContractID\":15,\"DiscountPerMonth\":null,\"ProductID\":null,\"ProductStateID\":null,\"Mail\":\"\",\"WithoutLimit\":true,\"ContractSold\":null,\"ContractLimit\":null,\"NumberOfTransactions\":null,\"DriverNameOnly\":null,\"DriverSurnameOnly\":null},{\"ID\":2881,\"CompanyID\":1155,\"CompanyName\":\"test\",\"FiscalCode\":null,\"Code\":\"test0000\",\"Limit\":125.000,\"StateID\":1,\"CardState\":\"Activ\",\"Deleted\":false,\"Sold\":132.330,\"StartDate\":\"\/Date(1436130000000+0300)\/\",\"InvoiceStartDate\":\"\/Date(-62135596800000+0200)\/\",\"Quantity\":null,\"Value\":0.0,\"CardTypeID\":1,\"CardType\":\"Credit\",\"SoldChanged\":false,\"DriverName\":\"aaa aaa\",\"VehiclePlateNumber\":\"aaa\",\"VehicleID\":null,\"Discount\":null,\"ContractID\":15,\"DiscountPerMonth\":null,\"ProductID\":null,\"ProductStateID\":null,\"Mail\":\"\",\"WithoutLimit\":true,\"ContractSold\":null,\"ContractLimit\":null,\"NumberOfTransactions\":null,\"DriverNameOnly\":null,\"DriverSurnameOnly\":null}]" }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How you converting json string into Object class ?

Comment: I thought ObjectMapper does that :)
That's why all my class variables are strings

Comment: I guess he is using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.

Comment: org.json.JSONObject;

Comment: `strResponse= strResponse.replace("\"GetCardsResult\":", "");` will destroy your JSON. You're only removing the key and the colon, not the leading and trailing curly braces. Additionally: your code is highly inefficient (has to work through the string up to four times) and likely to break (e.g. the webservice returns formatted JSON with a space in front of the colon)

Comment: I also noticed that the JSON collection is between ". I'm not sure this is correct.

Comment: disregard what method you use to deserialize your json, removing `"GetCardsResult":"` will result an invalid json, you need to remove `{     "GetCardsResult":"` from start of json, and remove `" }` from end of json to make it a valid ARRAY representation

Comment: I think the value of "GetCardsResult" is a `String` not a `JSONArray`.

Comment: @VladMarinescu Is it resolved?

Comment: Not really, no. If I try to erase { "GetCardsResult":"  and " } , i'll get a invalid JSON array

Comment: @VladMarinescu is the \ symbol in the response or did you get it while pasting the code from Android Studio?

Comment: I copy pasted the JSON response from WCF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    try {            
         JSONObject jsonObject = null;
         yourJSONString.replace("\\", "");
         jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourJSONString);
         String newJSONString = jsonObject.get("GetCardsResult").toString();
         JSONArray jsonMainArr = new JSONArray(newJSONString);
         //now just loop the json Array
         for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainArr.length(); ++i) {                     
         JSONObject rec = jsonMainArr.getJSONObject(i);                     
         card.set_id(rec.get("ID").toString());                     
         //....      
       }                                                       
       } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101844/discussion-between-vlad-marinescu-and-fabio-venturi-pastor).

Comment: yourJSONString.replace("\\", ""); Is it required??

Answer (score 2):

Try to use GSON its very efficient and easy to implement, As example below will be your POJO class.

```
public class Post {

    @SerializedName("id")
    public long ID;
    public String title;
    public String author;
    public String url;
    @SerializedName("date")
    public Date dateCreated;
    public String body;

    public List tags;

    public Post() {

    }
}

//Tag.java
public class Tag {

    public String name;
    public String url;

    public Tag() {

    }
}
```

And this will how you parse your JSON string to Object Class,

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(content);
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("M/d/yy hh:mm a");
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<Post>();
posts = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(reader, Post[].class));
content.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What do you pass to the mapper - string before or after compiling the regular expression?
2. Did you try any external lib like **Gson?** Everything you need is just `new Gson().fromJson(strResponse, new TypeToken<List<Card>>() {}.getType(););`

Comment: userCards= gs.fromJson(strResponse, new TypeToken<List<Card>>() {}.getType());

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2

Comment: what about new Gson().fromJson(strResponse, Card.class);

Comment: you thought that there's an object , not an array?

Comment: Can't convert Array to Card object. For sure, there's an array in JSON response. There are more than 1 card info, so , I need array , only if somehow I convert object by object